# Listserv strips recipient list, how do I turn that off?

Tags: mailing-lists

our university club has a few mailing lists provided by the university, and recently they migrated to LISTSERV. In general I like the interface and functionality, but there's a weird feature/bug(?) that I can't turn off:

Let's say my list is foo_list@university.com. Settings are public and confidential.

Now, if I write an email to a bunch of recipients, including foo_list, the recipients of that email list will, in their header, only see my name, i.e., they think I sent that email only to them, not to a bunch of other recipients.

I guess this is some sort of privacy feature, where someone posting to a mailing list doesn't want to expose all the various recipients to the subscribers of the email list. In our case, though, for the sake of a particular discussion email list, this is a much needed requirement.

How can I turn-off this recipient-stripping?

Comment: Probably not, on April 8th 2014 yahoo made a [sweeping policy change](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2141120/yahoo-email-antispoofing-policy-breaks-mailing-lists.html) that effectively changed the way every email list serv in the world works.   The best solution would be to get the university IT people assign an outgoing email address that's just for the list, instead of using your personal.